# Cannot load ssl localhost in WKWebView

Tags: localhost, wkwebview

Environment:

- iOS 10.15.3
- Xcode 11.3.1
- Swift 4.2

I have an Angular 5 app running locally at https://localhost:8300/vthome. I have installed a localhost cert and the page loads correctly without issue in chrome and safari.

I have an iOS app with a webview. I can load the Angular 5 app that is being served from our development server but I cannot load the version I have running locally.

When I try to load the Angular 5 app that is running locally in the webview in the simulator (iPhone 11 Pro Max 13.3):

```
    func loadWebViewUrl(url: String){
        let requestUrl = URL(string: url)
        print("Attempting to load url: \(requestUrl!)")
        let request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl!)

        webView.load(request as URLRequest)
    }
```

I get this error in the output:

```
Attempting to load url: https://localhost:8300/vthome
2020-02-18 09:12:35.263998-0600 PayBridge[23492:2718338] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2020-02-18 09:12:35.265999-0600 PayBridge[23492:2718338] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service
```

And the webview just shows blank (no text, no errors, nothing). I found a lot of issues regarding loading static html files but I couldn't find anything that addressed loading localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Although we are using HTTPS (TLS), iOS still did not like it. We solved this by adding: `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict> <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <true/> </dict>` to the info.plist file